# How to move an UIimageView random on the screen when you click the image

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uiviewanimation, uianimation

Can you help me please to move my image random on my View when I click it ?
I need to use UIView Animations (is required) and when the UIImageView is reaching the random destination on the screen it should change the color/image from inside.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

// ---- Is required to use UIView Animation ------

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1.png") // the second image is named "2.png"

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: view)
        let leftCorner = CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x + 48, y: touchLocation.y + 48)
        imageView.center = leftCorner
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's far easier to do this using a gesture recognizer than overriding the touch tracking.

Comment: And how can I do that ?
Because I'm using a Tap Gesture Recognizer. And at the moment when I touch the screen the picture is moving in the location where I touch the screen. But I want to touch the picture and picture to move somewhere else.
 Thanks !

Comment: There are many tutorials available. https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-gestures-tutorial-ios10 can get you started.

Comment: That tutorial is to drag and drop an image. I need to click the image and the image to respawn random on the screen.

Comment: All of the same principles apply. You just would translate the view.center differently when the gesture recognizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let imageViewWidth = CGFloat(100)
    let imageViewHeight = CGFloat(100)
    let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.gray, UIColor.brown, UIColor.green]

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(
            x: view.bounds.width/2 - imageViewWidth/2,
            y: view.bounds.height/2 - imageViewHeight/2,
            width: imageViewWidth,
            height: imageViewHeight
        )
        addTapRecognizerToImageView()
    }

    func addTapRecognizerToImageView() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func handleTap() {
        let maxX = view.frame.maxX-imageViewWidth
        let maxY = view.frame.maxY-imageViewHeight
        let randomX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxX)) + 0
        let randomY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxY)) + 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(
                x: CGFloat(randomX),
                y: CGFloat(randomY),
                width: self.imageViewWidth,
                height: self.imageViewHeight
            )
        }
        let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 0)
        imageView.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor]
    }

}
```